# O(n log n) with input of n^2

Tags: time-complexity

Could somebody explain me why when you have an algorithm A that has a time complexity of O(n log n) and give it input of size n^2 it gives the following: O(n^2 log n).

I understand that it becomes O(n^2 log n2) and then O(n^2 * 2 * log n) but why does the 2 disappear?

Comment: I believe that constant factors are discarded when dealing with O calculations, that's why the 2 would be gone in the result. But it's been a long while since I studied/did anything related to this, so I could be very wrong.

Comment: Yes, you can find some more info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity

Answer (score 0):

It disappears because time complexity does not care about things that have no effect when `n` increases (such as a constant multiplier). In fact, it often doesn't even care about things that have *less* effect.

That's why, if your program *runtime* can be calculated as `n3 - n + 7`, the *complexity* is the much simpler `O(n3)`. You can think of what happens as `n` approaches infinity. In that case, all the other terms become totally irrelevant compared to the first. That's when you're adding terms.

It's slightly different when multiplying since even lesser terms will still have a substantial effect (because they're *multiplied* by the thing having the most effect, rather than being added to).

For your specific case, `O(n2 log n2)` becomes `O(n2 2 log n)`. Then you can remove all terms that have no effect on the outcome as `n` increases. That's the `2`.